# How can subplot images from each folder?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm listing images with these code:

```
for folder in folder_list:
    img = os.path.join(f"{train_dir}/{folder}/00001.png")
    print(img)
```

output is:

> Fish/train/Black Sea Sprat/00001.png /Fish/train/Gilt-Head
> Bream/00001.png Fish/train/Hourse Mackerel/00001.png Fish/train/Red
> Mullet/00001.png /Fish/train/Red Sea Bream/00001.png Fish/train/Sea
> Bass/00001.png Fish/train/Shrimp/00001.png /Fish/train/Striped Red
> Mullet/00001.png Downloads/Fish/train/Trout/00001.
> there is 9 pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just printing image file names. You need to [enumerate](https://pythonbasics.org/enumerate/) the list of images and plot one by one using [plt.sublot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
files=[] #empty list
rows = 3 #Number of rows u need

for folder in folder_list:
    img = os.path.join(f"{train_dir}/{folder}/00001.png")
    files.append(img)
   
for num, x in enumerate(files):
    img = PIL.Image.open(x)
    plt.subplot(rows,6,num+1)
    plt.title(x.split('.')[0])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)
```